# "Shiver Me Timbers" hover text says "Warm Welcome"

Tags: bug, status-completed, winter-bash-2019

I realize I pay way too much attention to detail at times, but...

[image: "Shiver Me Timbers" hat hover text saying "Warm Welcome"]

So here's a bug report.

I'm on Firefox 70.0.1 (64-bit) for Linux Mint.

---

Other examples (which work correctly):

[image: "Warm Welcome" hat hover text saying "Warm Welcome"]

[image: "Silencium" hat hover text saying "Silencium"]

Comment: the warm welcome hat is directly to the right on your screen. Are you sure that you are not hovering over warm welcome by mistake?

Comment: All the others work fine for me.  Just this one exception.  I'm quite certain I'm not hovering over "Warm Welcome" by mistake.  (Are others able to reproduce this?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The tooltip confusion should now be fixed